# Formatting dates in Access

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, formatting, microsoft-access, database

I'm embarrassed with a seemingly very simple problem. I have about 7 million of rows in Access, with a date column formatted as numbers.  They are the 5 digit type of numbers excel uses when dates are formatted as numbers.  How do I reformat them as dates?

For example, in access:

[image: in Access]

should look like (in Excel):

[image: excel]

I tried using the built in date and time functions in Access to no avail.  I can't simply move the database to Excel, reformat, then move on with my life due to the number of rows I'm using.

I wouldn't post this unless I thought other people would refer back to this and learn something.

Comment: I rarely use Access, but, in 2016, select a cell in that column.  Then goto  `Fields` ► `Formatting` ► `Data Type` and change the data type to `Date/Time`

Comment: Can you share table design view screenshot.

Comment: excel also uses the numbers. If you want to see the dates, format the column as *Short Date* in excel